# Merge two json file using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm new to python. Can anyone help in solving this problem? 
I have this problem to merge json a and json b using unique id

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'e_data': {'reading':'', 'writing':''}},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'e_data': {'reading':'', 'writing':''}}]

b = [{'id':1,'reading':'2','writing':'3'}, 
    {'id':2,'reading':'3','writing':'3'}]
```

## Output

```
[{'id': 1,'name': 'a','e_data':{'reading':'2','writing':'3'}},{'id': 2,'name': 'b','e_data':{'reading':'3','writing':'3'}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'e_data': {'reading':'', 'writing':''}},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'e_data': {'reading':'', 'writing':''}}]

b = [{'id':1,'reading':'2','writing':'3'},
    {'id':2,'reading':'3','writing':'3'}]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if j['id'] == i['id']:
            i['e_data'].update(j)
            i['e_data'].pop('id')

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'e_data': {'reading': '2', 'writing': '3'}}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'e_data': {'reading': '3', 'writing': '3'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'e_data': {'reading':'', 'writing':''}},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'e_data': {'reading':'', 'writing':''}}]

b = [{'id':1,'reading':'2','writing':'3'}, 
    {'id':2,'reading':'3','writing':'3'}]

for dest in a:
    for source in b:
        if source['id'] == dest['id']:
            dest['e_data'].update(source)
a  

#[{'e_data': {'id': 1, 'reading': '2', 'writing': '3'}, 'id': 1, 'name': 'a'},
#{'e_data': {'id': 2, 'reading': '3', 'writing': '3'}, 'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]
```